# Simple Google Api example hangs on Outlook Addin

Tags: c#, outlook, google-api

I have a Win Form that is called from within a ribbon inside an Outlook Add-In.

This WinForm calls the following code:

```
 private void lnkReload_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
                     Run().Wait();
        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            // Create the service.
            var service = new DiscoveryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "Discovery Sample",
                ApiKey = Properties.Settings.Default.ClientId
            });

            // Run the request.
            Console.WriteLine("Executing a list request...");
            var result = await service.Apis.List().ExecuteAsync();

            // Display the results.
            if (result.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryList.ItemsData api in result.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(api.Id + " - " + api.Title);
                }
            }
        }
```

When debugging the code, at the line "car result=await"...

the code stops working. This sure can take SOME time, but reading that List should not take hours.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private async void lnkReload_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
          await Run();
        }
```